# Transforming custom coordinates to pixel in vector layer in OpenLayers 6

Tags: javascript, openlayers, d3

I have a XYZ layer for tiles(generated from an 1065 * 950 Image using gdal2tiles), and a vector layer for features, I want to use my own pixel transformation to set the coordinates of the features.

```js
 this.extent = [0, 0, this.imgWidth, this.imgHeight];

 this.projection = new Projection({
  code: "warehouse-tile-image",
  units: "pixel",
  extent: this.extent,
});

this.view = new View({
  projection: this.projection,
  center: getCenter(
   this.extent
  ),
  zoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 3,
});
this.tileSource = new XYZ({
  url: "assets/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  minZoom: 0,
  projection: this.projection,
  maxZoom: 3,
  tileSize: 256,
});
 this.layer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource(),
});
```

I want to use this D3 scale function to set the pixel coordinates:

```js
//The coordinate of data is in meter
const scale = 0.05
const max_x = scale* this.imgWidth + this.origin.x; 
const max_y = scale* this.imgHeight + this.origin.y;
this.xScale = scaleLinear()
  .domain([this.origin.x, max_x])
  .range([0, this.imgWidth]);
this.yScale = scaleLinear()
  .domain([this.origin.y, max_y])
  .range([this.imgHeight, 0]);
```

So I can transform the custom coordinates to pixel by using

> this.xScale(x) = pixel x

and

> this.yScale(y) = pixel y

This is how I do in Leaflet in order to re-projection:

```js
    const denominator = Math.pow(2, this.maxZoom);
    L.CRS.MySimple = L.Util.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
        /**
         * max zoom level >= log2(max(width,height)/tilesize)
         * a,c = 1 / 2^max zoom level
         **/
        transformation: new L.Transformation(
            1 / denominator, //a
            0, //b
            1 / denominator, //c
            0 //d
        ),
    });
 this.mapOptions = {
        layers: [
            L.tileLayer(this.tileUrl, {
                maxZoom: this.maxZoom,
                tileSize: 256,
                noWrap: true,
                bounds: bounds,
            }),
        ],
        zoom: this.maxZoom,
        crs: L.CRS.MySimple,
        maxZoom: this.maxZoom,
        minZoom: 0,
        maxBounds: bounds,
        zoomControl: false,
        center: L.latLng([this.imgWidth, this.imgHeight]),
    };
 private transformCoord(coordinate: { x: number; y: number }): number[] {
    //This function will transform custom coordinates to pixel coordinate using d3 scale
    return [this.xScale(coordinate.x), this.yScale(coordinate.y)];
}
//Feature geometry 
geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: this.transformCoord(data.pose.position),
            },
```

And then I just use those scale function to transform the coordinates to pixel coordinates and feed to the data layer (Leaflet-realtime which use a GeoJSON layer).

However, it is different in OpenLayers which seems to do the pixel transformation automatically for me.

My problem is I don't understand how the projections work in OpenLayers, I have no idea how to do the same as in Leaflet.

Answer (score 1):

You can define reverse scale functions, where all you have to do is to exchange `.domain` and `.range` values:

```
this.xScaleReverse = scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, this.imgWidth])
  .range([this.origin.x, max_x]);
this.yScaleReverse = scaleLinear()
  .domain([this.imgHeight, 0])
  .range([this.origin.y, max_y]);
```

Comment: It is still the same, I think I misunderstand the projection. In Leaflet I can use L.CRS.Simple to set my own coordinate system,and I can use those scale functions to transform my coordinates to pixel,then feed to Leaflet data layers, but I have no idea how to do it in OpenLayers. How do I define the view projection for custom tiles e.g. game or indoor map? I don't know what projection Openlayers uses to transform my coordinates to pixel. Is it the view projection I defined?

Comment: and I don't understand how to set the resolution, the scale is 0.05, meaning 1 pixel =0.05 meters

Comment: In the view of your comments question is completely different that I thought. Please edit your question with the additional info from your comments.

Comment: I have updated my question,plz have a look

Comment: I think I use the projection in the wrong way, there's no need to reproject the projection, the default one is measured in meters

Comment: Does this mean you resolved your question/problem?

Comment: Yes, I found it very simple, I was overcomplicated the problem. Thanks for helping